# How to use 'ticks' option while using CategoryAxisRenderer

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

I am trying to plot an line graph, i am using CategoryAxisRenderer.
I want to specify the ticks inside the `ticks` option

[Code link: jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2051/)

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var chartData = [["19-Jan-2012", 2.61], ["20-Jan-2012", 5.00], ["21-Jan-2012", 6.00]];

function PlotChart(chartData, extraDays) {


    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData], {
        title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,

            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                pad: 1,            
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer 
                ,ticks:["19-Jan-2012","20-Jan-2012","21-Jan-2012"]

            },
            yaxis: {
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '$%.2f'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
    });
}

PlotChart(chartData, 3);
```

The above piece of code works fine if i comment out the `ticks` option.
But with `ticks` option activated, it doesn't display the line on the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the data as `var chartData = [ 2.61, 5.00, 6.00];`
Now it works fine [**See Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2052/)

Code

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var chartData = [ 2.61, 5.00, 6.00];

function PlotChart(chartData, extraDays) {


    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData], {
        title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,

            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                pad: 1,
                // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the            
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                // renderer to use to draw the axis,  
               ticks:["19-Jan-2012","20-Jan-2012","21-Jan-2012"]

            },
            yaxis: {
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '$%.2f'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
    });
}

PlotChart(chartData, 3);
```